# Последовательная загрузка видео

Tags: python, opencv

Вопрос. В папке находится несколько видео. Необходимо их последовательно запускать  для дальнейшей обработки. Т.е. видео запускается - обрабатывается-закрывается - запускается новое

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_dir)
while
    "обработка файла"
break
```

Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cap.read()` возвращает код успеха и кадр.

Вот когда этот код становится False -  кадры кончились, можно закрыть текущий файл и открыть следующий.

Примерно так:

```
for img in fds: 
    if img.endswith(('.mp4')): 
         print(img) # 
         cap = cv2.VideoCapture(img)
         while True:
             ret, frame = cap.read()
             if ret:
                   обработать frame
             else:
                  break
         cap.release()
```

Comment: Вопрос заключается имеенно в последовательном присваивании имени файла, для того что бы он запускался. Например у меня есть код где я вывожу имя файла.
    
   fds = sorted(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\VIDEO"))
    for img in fds:
    if img.endswith(('.mp4')):
        print(img) # выводим имя файла
какой цикл должен получиться ?

Comment: Ну там же, где print, и вставить обработку кадров

Comment: Благодарю. Вроде работает.